# In what way const is interfering with marking a more specialized template when using pointers?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

I have this working code:

```
template <typename X, typename Y>
auto f(X a,  Y b) { return a + b; };

template <typename X, typename Y>
auto f(X* a,  Y* b) { return *a + *b; };

int main() {
    int* p;
    int* q;
    f(p, q);
}
```

which [compiles and runs](https://godbolt.org/z/K1vhjbq9Y) the second `f()`, because it is [more specialized](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65230288/7151494).

However, if we `const`-qualify the arguments like so:

```
template <typename X, typename Y>
auto f(const X a, const Y b) { return a + b; };

template <typename X, typename Y>
auto f(const X* a, const Y* b) { return *a + *b; };

int main() {
    int* p;
    int* q;
    f(p, q);
}
```

It [no longer works](https://godbolt.org/z/sdjcPq8rh) and tries to pick the first function, erroring out on the `a + b` for pointes.

Why does `const`-qualifying the types make the second template no longer more specialized?

Comment: `const X* a` is a non-`const` pointer to a `const` X. `p` and `q` both point to a non-`const` `int`.

Comment: @NathanPierson but the second template can match only pointers, while the first one can match anything. Wouldn't that quality it to be more specialized? Is the [linked asnwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65230288/7151494) wrong?

Comment: The template is more specialized, but the first overload is being selected earlier in the process. The [best viable function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Best_viable_function) first checks to see if one of the conversion sequences for the args is better. `int*` to `int * const` is an exact match. `int*` to `const int*` is a pointer conversion. So the first overload is selected during step 1, whereas "the second template is more specialized" only applies if they're tied as of step 5.

Comment: Actually, sorry, I think `int*` to `const int*` is a qualification conversion, not a pointer conversion, which would make both of them an exact match. Now I'm not sure what exactly is going on.

Comment: There might be something going on with the [thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39848541/why-should-i-not-use-const-in-this-simple-function) where `const`-qualifying a value parameter doesn't really have any effect from the perspective of calling code and overload resolution, so the first overload ends up being completely identical without even needing a qualification conversion. Can't seem to find a good definitive exposition of this though.

Comment: @NathanPierson "*`const`-qualifying a value parameter doesn't really have any effect from the perspective of calling code and overload resolution*" yeah, but if we ignore the `const`, we end up with the first snippet of code, which compiles successfully.

Comment: No, you don't. `X` and `const X` are the same in this context, `X*` and `const X*` are not. If you _actually_ added `const` [symmetrically](https://godbolt.org/z/M44vbjKae) you get something that does compile.

Comment: @NathanPierson true, true.

Answer (score 4):

> Why does `const`-qualifying the types make the second template no longer more specialized?

**It doesn't.**

The "problem" we're observing here is that overload resolution takes into account a few things *before* checking what type is more specialized.

Reading the section [Best viable function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Best_viable_function) we can see that:

> For each pair of viable function F1 and F2, the implicit conversion sequences from the `i`-th argument to `i`-th parameter are ranked to determine which one is better (except the first argument, the implicit object argument for static member functions has no effect on the ranking)
>
> F1 is determined to be a better function than F2 if implicit conversions for all arguments of F1 are *not worse* than the implicit conversions for all arguments of F2 [...]

Now let's take a look at both overloads:

```
template <typename X, typename Y>
auto f(const X a, const Y b) { return a + b; };

int main() {
    int* p;
    int* q;
    f(p, q);
}
```

Here `X = int*` and `Y = int*`. No conversions are necessary. It's worth to point out that the [types of `a` and `b` are not `const int*`, but `int* const`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1143272/7151494).

Let's now take a look at the second overload:

```
template <typename X, typename Y>
auto f(const X* a, const Y* b) { return *a + *b; };

int main() {
    int* p;
    int* q;
    f(p, q);
}
```

Here, in order to get `const int*` (the desired type of the argument) from `int*` (which is the type of `p` and `q`), `X` and `Y` have to be deduced as `int*` *and then a conversion has to occur*. That's because [`const int*` doesn't mean *`const` pointer to `int`*, but a *pointer to `const int`*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1143272/7151494). *Pointer to `const int`* and *pointer to `int`* are not the same, but the latter is convertible to the former. There is no way to deduce `X` and `Y` for it to be no conversions in this case.

Thus, overload resolution chooses the candidate with fewer conversions. That overload tries to add two pointers and it results in a compile-time error.

Comment: This is the best reason to prefer East Const (right const) as opposed to Const West.: compare `T const x` and `T const* c`.